# Bash: For loop - Ping entire IPV4 address space

Tags: bash, for-loop, nested, permutation, layer

How could I ping the entire IPV4 address space, with a `bash` `for` loop?
Obviously, it's not really practical, but it's just an example.
The question is less about networking utilities, and more about layering `for` loops with `bash` to produce all permutations of a set of numbers.
If that sounds like giberish, it's basically like trying to bruteforce a 4-digit PIN number on an access control keypad by punching in **every combination; *in sequence;*** from *0000* to *9999*.

I thought this would do it:

```
for x in {0..255}; 
do
    ping -c1 $x.$x.$x.$x; 
done
```

But instead of running each octet separately, like this:

> *0.0.0.**0**; 0.0.0.**1**; 0.0.0.**2**; → 255.255.255.25**3**; 255.255.255.25**4**; 255.255.255.25**5**;*

It came out looking more like this:

> ***0***.**0**.**0**.**0**; **1**.**1**.**1**.**1**; **2**.**2**.**2**.**2**; → 25**3**.25**3**.25**3**.25**3**; 25**4**.25**4**.25**4**.25**4**; 25**5**.25**5**.25**5**.25**5**;

Comment: FYI: If you guys feel like the title doesn't properly represent the question, and want to change it; you're welcome to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make 4 nested loops, like this:

```
for i in {0..255}
do
  for j in {0..255}
  do
    for k in {0..255}
    do
      for l in {0..255}
      do 
        ping -c1 $i.$j.$k.$l
      done
    done
  done
done
```